# Where can I find resource after installing an apk

Tags: android, apk

I want to know how to find a resource in an apk after installing it. I mean, whether Android will extract the apk and save into file system after installing.

By now, I only know apk will is saved in `/data/app`. `classes.dex` can be found in `dalvik-cache` directory. But I don't find any clue about resource in this apk, such as string.xml, png or any file in assets.  Is it possible that Android system unpack apk every time when it will use these resource?

I red many old thread, but I don't find answer yet. So can anyone please explain it for me?

Thanks very much in advance.

br

Answer (score 0):

The resources are inside the apk file as binary xml files. Also after the installation. For simple xml files it will load them only from the apk file. Images and larger file might be cached, but I don't know exactly where.

Answer (score 0):

only resources in res/raw folder will be available on device storage, otherwise it will be inside the apk as binary data

Answer (score 0):

To explore an Android APK file,
[ View the graphics, play the audio, etc.]

all you have to do,
is right click on an APK file,
and set it to "Open With" to WinZip, Winrar.
or your favorite unzipper.

Thereafter, any time you click on an APK file,
you can view the graphics, play the audio,
view the resources, explore the programming, etc.

If you want to convert an APK file to Linux/Unix,
download "Dex2Jar" from
http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/

then unzip one of the APK files
to a convenient directory,

navigate to the directory
and right click on the CLASSES.DEX file,
and set it to "Open With" "dex2jar".

Thereafter, anytime you click on an Android DEX file
this will convert the Android DEX file
to a Unix JAR file and put it in the directory
with the Android resources.

-- 
Tom Potter